# Split csv(not uniform) into 2 lists

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV with data in the format

```
1,2,3,4,A
2,3,B
1,4,5,6,C
5,D
```

and so on. How do i split it and assign each to python lists. The length of each line in csv is arbitrary. I need to split them into

```
   [[1,2,3,4],[2,3],[1,4,5,6],[5]]
```

and the rest into a python list

```
['A','B','C','D']
```

What is an efficient way to get this done. The below code is good enough to convert csv into list of lists but with the last elements. I want the last elements in a separate list

```
with open('dataset.csv', 'r') as fp:
  reader = csvreader(fp)
  li = list(reader)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate through the reader object and split/unpack the items into *all items excluding the last* and *last item*.

```
with open('dataset.csv', 'r') as fp:
  reader = csv.reader(fp)
  lst1, lst2 = [], []
  for row in reader:
      *others, last = row # Python 2: others, last = row[:-1], row[-1]
      lst1.append(others)
      lst2.append(last)
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, that would avoid the extra trip, but then the Python 2 alternative will have no where to stay :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', skipinitialspace=True)
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    for row in readCSV:
        list1.append(row[:-1])
        list2.append(row[-1])
print list1
print list2
```